# How to get Microsoft Teams Channel posts from powerapps?

Tags: microsoft-teams, powerapps

I have an app integrating with Microsoft Teams to get the list of teams linked to a user. I managed to get the list of teams by binding a gallery to `MicrosoftTeams.GetAllTeams().value` and another gallery items bound to `MicrosoftTeams.GetChannelsForGroup(FIRSTGallery.Selected.id).value`.

I saw there is a method to post a new comment to a channel but can't find anyway to get the existing posts in the selected channel.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way to do this yet. We are in the process of adding "Read" support to our Microsoft Graph APIs, which is what PowerApps uses under the covers, and once that is added PowerApps will add it too.

I'm afraid we don't have a specific date to share for when this will be supported.